# json string converted in python format in playbook

Tags: ansible

I want to launch multiple python scripts returning json on hosts and finally get a summary json :

```
{'server1': {script1_label: { stdout }, 
             script2_label: { stdout }
            },
 'server2': {script1_label: { stdout }, 
             script2_label: { stdout }
            },
}
```

stdout is the json output of each python script.

My playbook :

tasks:

```
- name: Execute Python Script
  shell: "python /srv/sources/{{ item.script }}"
  async: 30000
  poll: 10
  ignore_errors: yes
  failed_when: false
  register: "result"
  loop:
    - { script: 'checks_lines.py', variable: 'checks_lines' }
    - { script: 'checks_permissions.py', variable: 'checks_permissions' }

- debug:
    msg: "{ {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
                 {{ hostvars[host]['result']['results'] }},
             {% endfor %} }"
  run_once: true

- debug:
    msg: "{ {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
                 {{ hostvars[host]['result']['results'][0]['stdout'] }},
             {% endfor %} }"
  run_once: true

- debug:
    msg: "{ {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
              \"{{ host }}\":
              {
              {% for cmd in hostvars[host]['result']['results'] %}    
                  \"{{ cmd['item']['variable'] }}\" : {{ cmd['stdout'] }} ,
              {% endfor %}
              },
            {% endfor %} }"
  run_once: true
```

the first task returns :

```
{  [{'_ansible_parsed': True, 'stderr_lines': [], u'cmd': u'python /srv/sources/claranet/checks_lines.py', u'end': u'2020-03-19 11:18:11.784980', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'ansible_job_id': u'668039752167.115804', u'stdout': u'{"/etc/sysctl.conf": {"kernel.exec-shield": {"present": false, "value": []}}, "/etc/ssh/sshd_config": {"ClientAliveInterval": {"pres
ent": true, "value": ["0"]}, "ClientAliveCountMax": {"present": true, "value": ["3"]}}}', '_ansible_item_result': True, u'changed': True, u'start': u'2020-03-19 11:18:11.755788', u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params': u'python /srv/sources/claranet/checks_lines.py', u'removes': None, u'argv'
: None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdin': None}}, 'failed': False, u'finished': 1, 'item': {u'variable': u'checks_lines', u'script': u'checks_lines.py'}, u'rc': 0, u'delta': u'0:00:00.029192', 'stdout_lines': [u'{"/etc/sysctl.conf": {"kernel.exec-shield": {"present": false, "value": []}}, "/etc/ssh/sshd_config": {"ClientAliveInterval": {"present": 
true, "value": ["0"]}, "ClientAliveCountMax": {"present": true, "value": ["3"]}}}'], 'failed_when_result': False, u'stderr': u'', '_ansible_ignore_errors': True, '_ansible_item_label': {u'variable': u'checks_lines', u'script': u'checks_lines.py'}}, {'_ansible_parsed': True, 'stderr_lines': [], u'cmd': u'python /srv/sources/claranet/checks_permissions.py', u'
end': u'2020-03-19 11:18:23.654521', '_ansible_no_log': False, u'ansible_job_id': u'257312332479.116038', u'stdout': u'{"/etc/fstab": "644", "/etc/crontab": "644"}', '_ansible_item_result': True, u'changed': True, u'start': u'2020-03-19 11:18:23.635674', u'invocation': {u'module_args': {u'warn': True, u'executable': None, u'_uses_shell': True, u'_raw_params'
: u'python /srv/sources/claranet/checks_permissions.py', u'removes': None, u'argv': None, u'creates': None, u'chdir': None, u'stdin': None}}, 'failed': False, u'finished': 1, 'item': {u'variable': u'checks_permissions', u'script': u'checks_permissions.py'}, u'rc': 0, u'delta': u'0:00:00.018847', 'stdout_lines': [u'{"/etc/fstab": "644", "/etc/crontab": "644"}
'], 'failed_when_result': False, u'stderr': u'', '_ansible_ignore_errors': True, '_ansible_item_label': {u'variable': u'checks_permissions', u'script': u'checks_permissions.py'}}],  }
```

ok, stdout is a json string (python script output).

My second debug task return only one stdout :

```
{  {"/etc/sysctl.conf": {"kernel.exec-shield": {"present": false, "value": []}}, "/etc/ssh/sshd_config": {"ClientAliveInterval": {"present": true, "value": ["0"]}, "ClientAliveCountMax": {"present": true, "value": ["3"]}}},  }
```

ok, it is already a json string

My third task return the summary for all servers :

```
{'z98sl080pstemp9.cly.dtc3.cf.saint-gobain.net': {'checks_permissions': {'/etc/fstab': u'644', '/etc/crontab': u'644'}, 'checks_lines': {'/etc/sysctl.conf': {'kernel.exec-shield': {'present': False, 'value': []}}, '/etc/ssh/sshd_config': {'ClientAliveInterval': {'present': True, 'value': [u'0']}, 'ClientAliveCountMax': {'present': True, 'value': [u'3']}}}}}
```

The stdout is not a json string, but python format :

- ["3"] -> [u'3']
- true -> True
- Etc....

Why is my json string converted to python format ?

How to keep the json string ?

IS there a better to build the final json ?

Thanks.

David.

Answer (score 0):

I used a temporary variable(set_facts).
And it works....